# Printing the Bigger to smaller with Array on Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have this program:

```
int i;
double array[] = new double[10] ;
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in) ;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println("Give " + (i+1) + " number") ;
    array[i] = input.nextDouble();
}
double max = array[0], min =array[0];
int negative = 0 ;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    if(array[i] > max){
        max = array[i] ;
    }
    if (array[i] < min){
        min = array[i];
    }
}
//Difference between Biggest to Smaller number
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
// ...        
}
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    if(array[i] < 0){
    negative = negative + 1;
}
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        System.out.println("The double of  " + (i+1) + " is: " + (array[i] * 2) );
} 
System.out.println("\n" + "The Maximum is: " + max);
System.out.println("The Minimum : " + min);
System.out.println("The Difference between Biggest to Smaller is : "); 
System.out.println("Τhe count of negative objects are : " + negative);
```

---

I want to print the bigger to smaller number difference with values I have now.

I forgot what I need to add. I searched online, but the most of answers that I found, conflict with the whole program.

Any suggestion here?

Comment: i don't even understand what you want to do. do you want to print a list from highest to lowest or just those both values? what is not working? how should it work?

Comment: When posting your code, you should translate your comments in english so that we can have a better understanding of what you are trying to do

Comment: It's an exercise for school. The first is to count the biggest number and the smaller one. The 3rd one is to count how many negative numbers that I give. The 4th is to double the number that I give X2. I want to print now (on the 2nd "for") the difference between biggest and smaller number. I don't know if I make you understand. My english is not at the highest level.

Comment: Changed comments form Greek to English

Comment: *bigger to smaller.

Comment: The difference?  Like `max - min`?

Comment: It's confusing because you have a for-loop, but I think @Taylor hit the nail on the head with his comment

Comment: @Taylor Found. Thanks anyway.